# what is "ni" in JNI call here?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

```
(env)->GetMethodID(java_bitmap_class, "ni", "()I")
```

Normally in place of "ni" there is a documented method name, like `getRowBytes`. I suggest it may mean "native interface". But what is that, where I can find documentation for it?

Comment: The second parameter of that method is what it always is: the name of the method whose ID is being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this may help. Just try.

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and type 'ni' and find all in your document where it is present. 
Try to find where the 'ni' is defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is the name of the method in the java_bitmap_class that should be <strike>called</strike> returned.